# Dividing webpage with lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How do I divide my website page like this (stacked on mobile)? Preferably using bootstrap, but not necessarily.
[image]
[image]

This is my html code (this is the section I would like to divide):

```
<section>
    <div class="kj">
        <h3>The event and rules</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="kjb">
        <!--DIVIDE THIS PART-->
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS code:

```
 .kj {
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10%;
 }
 h3 {
 font-size: 7.0vw;
 color: #BDADAC;
 }
.kjb {
width: 60%;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 20%;
max-height: 80%;
padding-top: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Use Bootstrap `.row` and `.col` class own class for border

Comment: Show your css. Using two inline elements with width 50% will probably work. And don't use tables for layouting unless you're showing tabular data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="kj col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">The event and rules</h1>
      <h3 class="text-center">Event 1</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">Lorem ipsum Nostrud et in commodo pariatur deserunt culpa voluptate irure deserunt nulla et incididunt fugiat sit ullamco nostrud minim sed non laborum. Lorem ipsum Ut amet fugiat dolor do aliqua et commodo dolore voluptate ad Duis labore consectetur Duis laborum pariatur consectetur Ut amet laborum irure reprehenderit nisi nostrud fugiat ad qui in aliquip ea.
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="kjb">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <h3 class="text-center">Event 2</h3>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-8">Lorem ipsum Dolor veniam culpa laborum nulla est consectetur anim tempor incididunt mollit aliqua sit cupidatat elit minim nostrud qui pariatur tempor amet non magna aliqua irure sed veniam consequat voluptate labore. Lorem ipsum Quis Ut minim consequat est sed elit veniam quis dolor est culpa quis amet cillum do enim do consequat id sint ea esse commodo ut qui reprehenderit esse veniam ullamco ex commodo velit magna voluptate.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <h3 class="text-center">Event 3</h3>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-8">Lorem ipsum Aliquip deserunt magna fugiat ullamco do mollit tempor sunt dolor amet et irure incididunt ad adipisicing sunt aliquip tempor eiusmod adipisicing in irure magna ex reprehenderit aliqua culpa ea irure labore voluptate. Lorem ipsum Esse velit do tempor ea id sint culpa amet ad veniam sit irure cillum laborum dolore esse ut quis consectetur ex quis nostrud.</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

[Jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/mghLyzyv/)
Add your own class if you want to get border

Comment: I've added more code, and another picture of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap as suggested by @Sarjan

Without bootstrap(same as bootstrap css)

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
} 
section:after{
    display:table;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
}
.kj{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.kjb{
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I've added more code, and another picture of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with this:

```
<section>
    <div class="kj">
        <h3>The event and rules</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="kjb row">
        <!--DIVIDE THIS PART-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've added more code, and another picture of what I want.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using bootstrap, you should create two div containers with for example the `col-sm-6` class:

```
<section>
<div class="kj">
    <h3>The event and rules</h3>
</div>
<div class="kjb col-sm-6">
    <button class="register">
        Register
    </button>
</div>
<div class="kjb col-sm-6">
    right side
</div>
</section>
```

see: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

i've edited my code.... you have to duplicate the div container kjb and add the bootstrap class

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap. How do I keep the header the same, but divide the class .kjb into the three parts. I have updated, please check.

Comment: I've added more code, and another picture of what I want.